# Inequalities with $\|x-y\|$, $|\langle x,y\rangle|$, and $\sqrt{\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}}$ in a Hilbert space

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $\|x\|$ denote the norm of $x\in H$, and $\langle x,y\rangle$ denote the inner product of $x,y\in H$.

For $x,y\in H$ let us denote $\alpha(x,y)=\|x-y\|$, $\beta(x,y)=\sqrt{\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}}$, $\gamma(x,y)=|\langle x,y\rangle|$.

So, $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are nonnegative functions.

It is obvious that the following inequalities are true:
$$
\alpha\leq\beta\sqrt{2}, \quad \gamma\leq\frac{\beta^{2}}{2}.
$$

Are there functions $f,g,\varphi,\psi: [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ such that some of the following inequalities are true:
$$
\beta\leq f(\alpha), \quad \beta\leq g(\gamma), \quad \gamma\leq \varphi(\alpha), \quad \alpha\leq \psi(\gamma)?
$$

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- $\beta\leq f(\alpha)$?  No such $f$ exists.  Consider when $x=y\neq 0$.
- $\beta\leq g(\gamma)$?  No such $g$ exists.  Consider when $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular and not both zero.
- $\gamma\leq \varphi(\alpha)$? No such $\varphi$ exists.  Consider when $x=y\neq 0$.
- $\alpha\leq \psi(\gamma)$?  No such $\psi$ exists.  Consider when $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular and not both zero.

Comment: Thank you very much!

And what about the inequalities $\beta\leq g(\gamma)$ and $\alpha\leq \psi(\gamma)$ when $H=\mathbb{R}^{1}$?

That is,

i) Does there exist a function $g: [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ such that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
a^{2}+b^{2}\leq g(ab)?
$$

ii) Does there exist a function $\psi: [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ such that for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
|a-b|\leq \psi(ab)?
$$

Comment: @Marso725: "Consider when $x$ and $y$ are perpendicular and not both zero."  Note that this is still possible in $1$ dimension.  (I didn't say "both not zero".)

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, it is obvious!